# draggable image remove background

Tags: jquery, html

see http://liveweave.com/d8F0Qw

i want when image is beign dragged only image gets dragged not with dotted border:

how can i do this :

i tried :

```
helper: function(event) {
                return $(this).css({'background': 'none'}).clone();
        },
```

but this remove backgroud for main image also

how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any additional JavaScript. jQuery UI adds "activity" classes to the elements on which it is operating. In the case of a draggable, the class is `ui-draggable-dragging`, so you can just add this rule to your CSS:

```
#image-list li.ui-draggable-dragging {
  border:  none;  
}
```

In the future, your questions will be greatly improved by simplifiying your code and posting those snippets. The question was around behavior while dragging, so we didn't really need to see your canvas-handling code. See the snippet below.

Admittedly, it's sometimes hard to know where to look to fix the bad behavior, but simplifying your code not only helps people answer the question, it helps you figure out what each section of the code is doing.

```js
$(function(){
  var $gallery = $('#image-list li');
  $gallery.draggable();
});
```

```css
#image-list li{
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
  cursor:move;
}

#image-list li.ui-draggable-dragging {
  border:  none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

<ul id="image-list"><li><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Aurora_as_seen_by_IMAGE.PNG" class="draggable-image"></li>
</ul>
```